Seeing the previous details in a component
I have a component that, dispatches an action that calls an API that updates a redux store and displays the updated store via a selector
The trouble I'm having is that when I navigate away from the component and comeback, the previous information is in the UI for a second before it updates to the new information
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "@/lib/hooks/store.hooks";

import styles from "@/styles/components/_detail.module.scss";
import {
  getAlbum,
  selectAlbumDetail,
} from "@/lib/features/music/musicSlice";

import { AlbumDetail } from "@/shared/interfaces/music";

const initialAlbumDetail: AlbumDetail = {
  artists: [],
  image: "",
  name: "",
  release_date: "",
  spotify_link: "",
  tracks: [""],
  category: "",
};

const AlbumDetails = ({ params: { id } }: { params: { id: string } }) => {

const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const [albumDetails, setAlbumDetails] =
    useState<AlbumDetail>(initialAlbumDetail);

const album: AlbumDetail = useAppSelector(selectAlbumDetail);

const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true);

const fetchAlbumDetails = useCallback(() => {
    setIsFetching(true);
    dispatch(getAlbum(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAlbumDetails(initialAlbumDetail);
    fetchAlbumDetails();
  }, [fetchAlbumDetails]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (album) {
      setAlbumDetails(album);
      setIsFetching(false);
    }
  }, [album]);

  if (isFetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <div>{albumDetails.name}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AlbumDetails;


I think  you should put const album: AlbumDetail = useAppSelector(selectAlbumDetail); inside useEffect so that everytime the component laods it's value is fetched directly from the selector

Move the loading state into the store so it's persisted along with the album state value. Don't duplicate the Redux state into local component state as this is a React anti-pattern.

@AniketPandey That won't work as React hooks can't be called in callback functions. Calling useAppSelector in the useEffect callback breaks the Rules of Hooks.

the best way I found to solve this was to create a redux action/reducer to clear the details
clearAlbumDetails: create.reducer((state) => {
      state.selectedAlbum = {} as AlbumDetail;
 }),

And then dispatch the action on the page that I navigate to when leaving this one.
